# how to get the type of input?

Tags: jquery, forms, input

How to get the type of input in the form by its name? for example:

```
<input type="text" value="123" name="username" />
```

the return type should be "text".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> document.getElementsByName("username")[0].type
"text"
```

Comment: That's not even a jQuery answer.

Comment: Well, the request was for a jQuery solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type="text" value="123" name="username" id="username" />

getInputType("#username");

getInputType("input[name=username]");


function getInputType(selector){ 
  var inputType = $(selector).attr('type');
  alert(inputType);
  return inputType;
}
```

Comment: is it possible without the id?

Comment: yes i just made the change to show you how. notice the selector changed in the call to the method